# Angular 2 Http RetryWhen

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, angular-http

I'm trying to use `retryWhen` in HTTP calls.

It works perfectly when try to use like this:

```
return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/track/${this.user.instance._id}/${this.currentPlayer.playlist.id}/next?s=${this.playerCounter}`, options)
      .timeout(500, new TimeoutError(`Timeout trying to get next track. [instanceId=${this.user.instance._id}]`))
      .retryWhen(attempts => {
        return Observable.range(1, 3).zip(attempts, i => i).flatMap(i => 3 === i ? Observable.throw(attempts) : Observable.timer(i * 1000));
      })
```

It makes a maximum of 3 tries if get a Timeout error.

But, always have a buuut, I want to make this more abstract to use on various use cases and for this, I have to check the type of the error.

**Only TechnicalErros will be retried.**

So I tried this without success.

```
.retryWhen(attempts => {
    return attempts.flatMap(error => {
      if(error instanceof TechnicalError) {
        return Observable.range(1, 3).zip(attempts, i => i).flatMap(i => 3 === i ? Observable.throw(attempts) : Observable.timer(i * 1000));
      } else {
        Observable.throw(error);
      }
    });
  })
```

It stops at first try and does not execute the `Observable.timer()`, neither the `Observable.throw()`.

I have almost sure that the problem is about the first `flatMap`, I already tried to use `mergeMap`, without success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In RxJS 5 `flatMap()` is just alias to `mergeMap()` :).

The problem is in the way you use the callback for `retryWhen()` operator. It's called just once and then every time an error signal arrives it's pushed to the Observable returned from this callback.

In your second example you're returning Observable from `attempts.flatMap` and then subscribing to it again that callback with `.zip(attempts, i => i)`. But this `zip` operator is never called because it's called after the value has been already consumed by `attempts.flatMap`. Also this is why the `Observable.range(1, 3)` starts always from the beginning.

I know this looks confusing. Just be aware thet:

- the callback for `retryWhen()` is called just once.
- the callback for `attempts.flatMap()` is called every time an error arrives.

So you just need to restructure your code, for example like the following:

```
var source = Observable.create(obs => {
        obs.next(1);
        obs.next(2);
        obs.error(new TechnicalError('error from source'));
    })
    .retryWhen(attempts => {
        console.log('retryWhen callback');
        let count = 0;

        return attempts.flatMap(error => {
            if (error instanceof TechnicalError) {
                console.log(error);
                return ++count >= 3 ? Observable.throw(error) : Observable.timer(count * 1000);
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        });
    })
    .subscribe(
        val => console.log(val),
        err => console.log('subscribe error', err),
        _ => console.log('complete')
    );
```

This prints to console:

```
1
2
retryWhen callback
TechnicalError { msg: 'error from source' }
1
2
TechnicalError { msg: 'error from source' }
1
2
TechnicalError { msg: 'error from source' }
subscribe error TechnicalError { msg: 'error from source' }
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/hobeda/3/edit?js,console

Comment: Hi, it works pretty well, would be more elegant if we could use the "range" operator and get rid of the counter variable, but it works pretty well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue and found a way to use range operator to generate the retries count instead of the counter variable, here is the code:

```
  var source = Observable.create(obs => {
  obs.next(1);
  obs.next(2);
  obs.error(new TechnicalError('error from source'));
})
  .retryWhen(error => {
    console.log("Error occured, retryWhen initialized");
    return error.zip(Observable.range(1, 4), (error, i) => {
      return {
        ErrorObj: error,
        RetryCount: i
      }
    })
      .map(obj => {
        if (error instanceof TechnicalError) {
          if (obj.RetryCount > 3)
            throw obj.ErrorObj;
          //Retry every one sec for 3 times
          console.log('Retry # ' + obj.RetryCount);
          return Observable.timer(obj.RetryCount * 1000);
        }
        else {
          throw obj.ErrorObj;
        }
      }).concatAll()
  })
  .subscribe(
  val => console.log(val),
  err => console.log('subscribe error', err),
  _ => console.log('complete')
  );
```

The idea is to place the range operator where it will be initialized only once (the retryWhen callback) this way the zip operator will combine any error with a new range number and pass this to the map operator to do the error check logic